# Stepper motor runs at full speed, then abruptly slows

Tags: dc-motor, hat, adafruit, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm, step-motor

I'm working with a Nema 17 adafruit stepper motor, item #324, running on Raspberry Pi 4b (Bookworm OS) with an Adafruit DC & Stepper Motor HAT for Raspberry Pi - Mini Kit Product ID: 2348.

I have a problem where the motor runs at top speed for a few seconds, then slows down and doesn't speed back up.  No excessive heat noted on motor or pi. You can see exactly what I'm talking about here.  [url][https://www.youtube.com/shorts/vlc2USj2kgw[/url]](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/vlc2USj2kgw%5B/url%5D).  Sorry about the rumbling in the background, had a fan going in a closed room.   Watch the amperage display in the back which jumps when the motor slows down.  During high speed it's pulling ~0.10 amps, when it slows down it pulls almost double that.  It does seem to stutter a time or two also.

I have ran a number of tests, and it seems to do this randomly on 99% of the runs.

The motor is ran from the terminal using the python3 test program shown below.

```
import board
from adafruit_motor import stepper
from adafruit_motorkit import MotorKit
import sys

# Below initialises the variable kit to be our I2C Connected Adafruit Motor HAT
kit = MotorKit(i2c=board.I2C())

for i in range(4000):
    kit.stepper1.onestep()
#    time.sleep(length)
# The below line will de-energise the Stepper Motor so it can freely move
kit.stepper1.release()
```

I need to be able to do a consistent run without the motor slowing down.  Putting a time.sleep in it doesn't reliably fix the problem.

Any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

GWFAMI